# Wordpress Give user role to edit users

Tags: wordpress

Trying to give user role to edit other users:

```
$edit_editor = get_role('designer');
$edit_editor->add_cap('edit_users');
$edit_editor->add_cap('list_users');
$edit_editor->add_cap('promote_users');
$edit_editor->add_cap('create_users');
$edit_editor->add_cap('add_users');
$edit_editor->add_cap('delete_users');
```

Now user able to get to Users list section but unable to edit existing users. How can i fix this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add roles so:

```
$result = add_role(
        'editor_of_users',
        __( 'Editor of Users' ),
        array(
           'edit_users' => true,
           // Add more capabilities...
        )
    );
    if ( null !== $result ) {
        echo 'Yay! New role created!';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Oh... the editor_of_users role already exists.';
    }
```

For more information you can red the documentation about: [add_role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)

And the all users capabilities here: [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)